# Horizontally center fractions (and expressions) in table

Tags: tables, math-mode, fractions

I am trying to center my fractions, but it seems to be shifted upward relative to the center of the boxes. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{interval}


\intervalconfig{
    soft open fences,
    separator symbol=, ,
} 

\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-2cm}HW 8}
    \author{John Doe}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =*]
        \item Looking at $x$, we see that $T = 0.2\pi$, so $x = \sin\left(10t\right)$. Therefore, 
        $$\bm{\Phi}\left(t\right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \sin\left(10t\right) & \sin^2\left(10t\right) & \sin^3\left(10t\right) & \sin^4\left(10t\right)\end{bmatrix}^T
        $$
        Next,
        $$\bm{\Phi}\left(t\right)\bm{\Phi}^T\left(t\right) =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & \sin\left(10t\right) & \sin^2\left(10t\right) & \sin^3\left(10t\right) & \sin^4\left(10t\right)\\
            \sin\left(10t\right) & \sin^2\left(10t\right) & \sin^3\left(10t\right) & \sin^4\left(10t\right) & \sin^5\left(10t\right)\\
            \sin^2\left(10t\right) & \sin^3\left(10t\right) & \sin^4\left(10t\right) & \sin^5\left(10t\right) & \sin^6\left(10t\right)\\
            \sin^3\left(10t\right) & \sin^4\left(10t\right) & \sin^5\left(10t\right) & \sin^6\left(10t\right) & \sin^7\left(10t\right)\\
            \sin^4\left(10t\right) & \sin^5\left(10t\right) & \sin^6\left(10t\right) & \sin^7\left(10t\right) & \sin^8\left(10t\right)
        \end{bmatrix}
        $$
        Then, the PE condition is evaluated as
        $$\int_{t}^{t+T}\bm{\Phi}\left(\tau\right)\bm{\Phi}^T\left(\tau\right) d\tau=
        \int_{t}^{t+T}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & \sin\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^2\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^3\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^4\left(10\tau\right)\\
            \sin\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^2\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^3\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^4\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^5\left(10\tau\right)\\
            \sin^2\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^3\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^4\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^5\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^6\left(10\tau\right)\\
            \sin^3\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^4\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^5\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^6\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^7\left(10\tau\right)\\
            \sin^4\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^5\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^6\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^7\left(10\tau\right) & \sin^8\left(10\tau\right)
        \end{bmatrix} d\tau
        $$
        We now take a look at each trig integral with different powers.
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                $n$ & $\mathlarger{\int\sin^n\left(10\tau\right)d\tau}$\\ [12pt]
                \hline
                0 & $\tau$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                1 & $-\dfrac{\cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                2 & $\dfrac{\tau}{2} - \dfrac{\sin\left(20\tau\right)}{40}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                3 & $\dfrac{\frac{\cos^3\left(10\tau\right)}{3} - \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                4 & $\dfrac{120\tau - 8\sin\left(20\tau\right) + \sin\left(40\tau\right)}{320}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                5 & $\dfrac{-\frac{\cos^5\left(10\tau\right)}{5} + \frac{2\cos^3\left(10\tau\right)}{3}- \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                6 & $\dfrac{600\tau + 4\sin^3\left(20\tau\right) - 48\sin\left(20\tau\right) + 9\sin\left(40\tau\right)}{1920}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                7 & $\dfrac{\frac{\cos^7\left(10\tau\right)}{7} - \frac{3\cos^5\left(10\tau\right)}{5} + \cos^3\left(10\tau\right) - \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                8 & $\dfrac{8400\tau + 128\sin^3\left(20\tau\right) - 768\sin\left(20\tau\right) + 168\sin\left(40\tau\right) + 3\sin\left(80\tau\right)}{30720}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Trig integrals for powers of $n \in [0,8] \in \mathbb{Z}$.}
        \end{table}
        Then, with $T = 0.2\pi$ and applying the integral bounds, we get the following:
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                $n$ & $\mathlarger{\int_{t}^{t+T}\sin^n\left(10\tau\right)d\tau}$\\ [12pt]
                \hline
                0 & $0.2\pi$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                1 & $0$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                2 & $0.1\pi$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                3 & $0$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                4 & $\dfrac{3\pi}{40}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                5 & $0$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                6 & $\dfrac{\pi}{16}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                7 & $0$\\[12pt]
                \hline
                8 & $\dfrac{7\pi}{128}$\\[12pt]
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output that I currently have:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to center them?

Comment: Take a look at the cellspace package or at makegapedcells from the makecell package.

Comment: While `\arraystretch` adds more space above and below the baseline, they are not equal, nor is the baseline centered.  You could use `\fbox` with `\fboxrule=0pt`, but this really is a job for cellspace.

Answer (score 6):

A `cellspace` package solution, in which

- all `[12pt]` used in `\\[12pt]` is deleted, since this only adds vertical space to bottom of tabular cells.
- `cellspace` is loaded and two length changed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|Oc|Oc|}
      \hline
      $n$ & $\mathlarger{\int\sin^n\left(10\tau\right)d\tau}$\\ 
      \hline
      0 & $\tau$\\
      \hline
      1 & $-\dfrac{\cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
      \hline
      2 & $\dfrac{\tau}{2} - \dfrac{\sin\left(20\tau\right)}{40}$\\
      \hline
      3 & $\dfrac{\frac{\cos^3\left(10\tau\right)}{3} - \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
      \hline
      4 & $\dfrac{120\tau - 8\sin\left(20\tau\right) + \sin\left(40\tau\right)}{320}$\\
      \hline
      5 & $\dfrac{-\frac{\cos^5\left(10\tau\right)}{5} + \frac{2\cos^3\left(10\tau\right)}{3}- \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
      \hline
      6 & $\dfrac{600\tau + 4\sin^3\left(20\tau\right) - 48\sin\left(20\tau\right) + 9\sin\left(40\tau\right)}{1920}$\\
      \hline
      7 & $\dfrac{\frac{\cos^7\left(10\tau\right)}{7} - \frac{3\cos^5\left(10\tau\right)}{5} + \cos^3\left(10\tau\right) - \cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
      \hline
      8 & $\dfrac{8400\tau + 128\sin^3\left(20\tau\right) - 768\sin\left(20\tau\right) + 168\sin\left(40\tau\right) + 3\sin\left(80\tau\right)}{30720}$\\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Trig integrals for powers of $n \in [0,8] \in \mathbb{Z}$.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: cellspace package example]

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late to the party, but hopefully still useful. Rather than focus one's efforts on achieving vertical centering between successive horizontal lines, I'd recommend getting rid of the horizontal (as well as vertical) lines. This approach also lets me get rid of all `[12pt]` spacers.

Next, those long fraction bars look very forbidding. I think your readers will appreciate you replacing the `\frac{<very long numerator>{<short denominator>}` expressions with `\frac{1}{<short denominator>}[<very long numerator>]` expressions.

I'd also use a `longtable` environment instead of a `table`/`tabular` combination, in order to allow an automatic page break if and when needed.

Finally, do get rid of the multitude of `\left` and `\right` sizing directives: They accomplish *nothing* -- except to mess with TeX's fine horizontal spacing rules.

[image]

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, bm, graphicx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\usepackage{float,enumitem, interval}
\intervalconfig{soft open fences,separator symbol=, } 

\newcommand\mymat{%
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
          1 &   \sin(10t) & \sin^2(10t) & \sin^3(10t) & \sin^4(10t)\\
  \sin(10t) & \sin^2(10t) & \sin^3(10t) & \sin^4(10t) & \sin^5(10t)\\
\sin^2(10t) & \sin^3(10t) & \sin^4(10t) & \sin^5(10t) & \sin^6(10t)\\
\sin^3(10t) & \sin^4(10t) & \sin^5(10t) & \sin^6(10t) & \sin^7(10t)\\
\sin^4(10t) & \sin^5(10t) & \sin^6(10t) & \sin^7(10t) & \sin^8(10t)
\end{bmatrix*}}

\begin{document}
\title{\vspace{-2cm}HW 8}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]
\item Looking at $x$, we see that $T = 0.2\pi$, so $x = \sin(10t)$. Therefore, 
\[
\bm{\Phi}(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & \sin(10t) & \sin^2(10t) & \sin^3(10t) & \sin^4(10t)
\end{bmatrix}^T
\]
Next,
\[
\bm{\Phi}(t)\bm{\Phi}^T\!(t) = \mymat
\]

Then, the PE condition is evaluated as
\[
\int_{t}^{t+T}\bm{\Phi}(\tau)\bm{\Phi}^T\!(\tau)\, d\tau=
\int_{t}^{t+T} \mymat d\tau
\]
The following table shows the trig integrals for various powers of $n$.
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}l<{$} >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} @{}}
\caption{Trig integrals for powers of $n \in \{0,1,\dots,8\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.}\\
\toprule
n & \int\sin^n(10\tau)\,d\tau\\ \addlinespace
\midrule
0 & \tau\\ \addlinespace
1 & -\frac{1}{10}\cos(10\tau) \\ \addlinespace
2 & \frac{\tau}{2} - \frac{1}{40}\sin(20\tau) \\ \addlinespace
3 & \frac{1}{10}\bigl[\tfrac{1}{3}\cos^3(10\tau) - \cos(10\tau)\bigr] \\ \addlinespace
4 & \frac{1}{320}\bigl[120\tau - 8\sin(20\tau) + \sin(40\tau)\bigr] \\ \addlinespace
5 & \frac{1}{10}\bigl[-\tfrac{1}{5}\cos^5(10\tau) + \tfrac{2}{3}\cos^3(10\tau)- \cos(10\tau) \bigr] \\ \addlinespace
6 & \frac{1}{1920}\bigl[600\tau + 4\sin^3(20\tau) - 48\sin(20\tau) + 9\sin(40\tau) \bigr]\\ \addlinespace
7 & \frac{1}{10}\bigl[ \tfrac{1}{7}\cos^7(10\tau) - \tfrac{3}{5}\cos^5(10\tau) + \cos^3(10\tau) - \cos(10\tau) \bigr] \\ \addlinespace
8 & \frac{1}{30720}\bigl[8400\tau + 128\sin^3(20\tau) - 768\sin(20\tau) + 168\sin(40\tau) + 3\sin(80\tau) \bigr] \\\addlinespace 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

With $T = 0.2\pi$ and applying the integral bounds, we get:
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}l<{$} >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} @{}}
\toprule
n & \int_{t}^{t+T} \sin^n(10\tau)\,d\tau \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
1,3,5,7 & 0 \\\addlinespace
0 & 0.2\pi \\ \addlinespace
2 & 0.1\pi \\ \addlinespace
4 & (3/40) \pi \\ \addlinespace
6 & (1/16)\pi\\ \addlinespace
8 & (7/128)\pi \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent solution provided by @muzimuzhi regarding cellspace I have also added the option of \makegapedcell -- please have a look

You could add \addlinespace as a third option to get extra space with the booktabs package but the downside is you would have to remove the \hline which would show gaps otherwise

I have removed some packages and also the `n` in the first column since unicode errors were being thrown-- I am sure you will recover

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[column=o]{cellspace}%
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|oc|oc|}
                \hline
                & $\mathlarger{\int\sin^n\left(10\tau\right)d\tau}$\\
                \hline
                0 & $\tau$\\
                \hline
                1 & $-\dfrac{\cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
                \hline
                2 & $\dfrac{\tau}{2} - \dfrac{\sin\left(20\tau\right)}{40}$\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htbp]            
            \centering\makegapedcells
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                & $\mathlarger{\int\sin^n\left(10\tau\right)d\tau}$\\
                \hline
                0 & $\tau$\\
                \hline
                1 & $-\dfrac{\cos\left(10\tau\right)}{10}$\\
                \hline
                2 & $\dfrac{\tau}{2} - \dfrac{\sin\left(20\tau\right)}{40}$\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```